# No module named 'flask' when I'm not using it

Tags: python, image, text

while I'm triyng to turn an image into text this error happens even tho I'm not using flask module. I even downloaded flask and it's still showing that.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeBzb.png)

import pywhatkit

image = "image.png"
text = "text.txt"

pywhatkit.image_to_ascii_art(image, text)

Comment: Please paste your code as text.

Comment: If you don't have `flask` installed then you need to stall it because it seems the package you are trying to use needs `flask`.

Comment: _I even downloaded flask and it's still showing that_ Apparently you downloaded it but didn't install it.

Comment: I installed it.

Comment: @Tobias07 how did you install it?

Comment: I "pip installed" it and it's still happening

Comment: Are you running code in the same environment you're installing modules to? Seems like you aren't.

Comment: @JohnGordon you were right, sorry. Thanks for help it's working :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.